# Need help in porting a function from C++ to Ocaml

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, functional-programming, ocaml

I have the following function code in C++

```
bool SolveSudoku(int grid[N][N])
{
int row, col;

if (!FindUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col))
   return true;

for (int num = 1; num <= 9; num++)
{
    if (isSafe(grid, row, col, num))
    {
         grid[row][col] = num;
         if (SolveSudoku(grid))
            return true;

         grid[row][col] = UNASSIGNED;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

The issue that I am facing here is that, in the if statement, I need to first perform an operation and then return a Boolean value. And Ocaml is not helpful in that way with different return values in same if statement.

Comment: Of course you can first perform some function and then return another value in if clauses. See for example the ignore function.

Comment: And then it seems ridiculous trying to translate imperative statements to functional expressions 1 to 1. Maybe the cause of the downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the source code of OCaml version of sudoku:

https://github.com/VictorNicollet/99-Problems-OCaml/blob/master/91-99/p97.ml